# Error: Cannot resolve method shutdownInput(),shutdownOutput(),close()

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
public void exit() {
    for (Iterator<Socket> iterator = sockets.values().iterator();iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        Socket socket = iterator.next();
        try{
            socket.shutdownInput();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            socket.close();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error: `Cannot resolve method shutdownInput(),shutdownOutput(),close()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `iterator.next()`, it's going to return an Object, not a Socket. So you have to cast the returned object to a Socket. So you would do:

```
Socket socket = (Socket) iterator.next();
```